# POWER BI: How to use parameter as column name

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I have a Power BI Table with the following columns : the first one has a list of server names, all other columns names are numbers that are actually week numbers (each week, a new columns gets added). In each of these Week columns is the server status for that week : active or inactive (1 or null).

| Server Name | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAA | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | null |
| BBBB | null | null | null | null | null |
| CCCC | null | null | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| DDDD | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I would like to have a comparison in a new "Status" column from week to week. For instance, if Server X was active on week 24 and on Week 25 its Status should be "Active"; if Server X was active on week 24 and inactive on week 25 the Status should be "Deactivated", if Server X was inactive on week 24 and active on week 25 the Status should be "Activated", etc.

I want the user, on the report page, to be able to enter a week number through a parameter(ie. "24") and then, the new calculated Status column makes the comparison between the selected week and the previous one. In the Status column, for each server name, I want to have its status evolution for the selected week (ie. 24) and the week before (ie. 23).

The goal is to have, for the selected week, the number of active, activated, deactivated and inactive servers compared to the previous one.

How do I do that?

Comment: The first thing you do is Unpivot the week numbers so you end up with (ServerName, WeekNumber, Status) Then the question becomes fairly trivial, because you can use CALCULATE() to retrieve the previous time period (week, day, month, etc) and the value associated with it. In other words, you don't use a parameter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Post some data and I'll show you how to unpivot it. Once your table looks like this (ServerName, Date, Status), it's really easy.

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCk4tKkstUtJRMgRiIyA2BmITIDYFYjMgNleK1YEpUwAp8gRiRyTsCcdICo2QJBwxMJJCYyRTME1FUmhCrNWmKBKomoAKYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t, Column3 = _t, Column4 = _t, Column5 = _t, Column6 = _t, Column7 = _t, Column8 = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}}),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Server", type text}, {"1", type text}, {"2", type text}, {"3", type text}, {"4", type text}, {"5", type text}, {"6", type text}, {"7", type text}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Server"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "WeekNumber"}}),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"WeekNumber", Int64.Type}}),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type2",{{"Value", "ServerStatus"}})
```

in
#"Renamed Columns1"

Then the measure for the Previous Week Status is just:

```
Status PW = CALCULATE(MIN('ServerActivity'[ServerStatus]),
                FILTER('ServerActivity',
                    [WeekNumber]=MAX('ServerActivity'[WeekNumber])-1),
                    'ServerActivity'[Server] = MAX('ServerActivity'[Server]))
```

Comment: OK so initially, my table was unpivoted, I only had a list of server names and a date, and in the server was inactive one week, it wasn't in the list for that week. If prsent in list = active; if not = inactive. That is why I had to do a Group By the Pivot the week columns, so that I would have a line for each server, regardless of if it was active of not that week : 1 if "active", null if "inactive". Do you think your solution would still work that way?

Answer (score 0):

Current week:

```
CW Status = CALCULATE(MIN([Status]),
 FILTER(
    ALL('ServerActive'),
        [Server Name]=MAX('ServerActive'[Server Name]) && 
        [WeekNumber]=MAX([WeekNumber])
        )
    )
```

Not sure what to call this one:

```
Final Status:=
 SWITCH(TRUE(),
      [PW Status]=1 && [CW Status]=1, "Active",
      [PW Status]=1 && [CW Status]=0,"Deactivated",
      [PW Status]=0 && [CW Status]=1,"Activated",
    "Other")
```